Changing the color of a text using Flask-Socketio in multiplayer
There is a button and whenever you click on it, it is supposed to toggle the color of the text below. It should also work in multiplayer, i.e: If u change the color, and if the other person also clicks on the button, it should change the color of the text back to the original color.I have a basic idea on how I would do this:

Have a button and a text with the class colored or uncolored.
Whenever a person clicks on the it emits a socketio event to the server side.
When the server receives the event from the server side, it broadcasts another event to all the people   connected to the server.
When the client recieves the event, it checks if the class of the text is colored or not and changes  accordingly using if else statements. 
It should be working but it doesn't work and takes a lot of time to load the webpage 

Code:

main.py
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
from flask_socketio import emit, SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "secret_key"
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@socketio.on("changeColorClient")
def changeColorServer(data):
    emit("changeColorServer", {"message" : "changed color"}, broadcast=True)
    print(data["message"])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, use_reloader=True, log_output=True, debug=True)

style.css -> basically .colored: {some color of the text} and .uncolored: {some color of the text}
index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Color changer multiplayer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.0.1/socket.io.js" integrity="sha512-q/dWJ3kcmjBLU4Qc47E4A9kTB4m3wuTY7vkFJDTZKjTs8jhyGQnaUrxa0Ytd0ssMZhbNua9hE+E7Qv1j+DyZwA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="button" onClick="changeColorClient()" class="uncolored">Click me to change the color of the text below</button>
    <h4 id="text">When you click the button above me you'll be able to change the color of my text.<br>This is can work in multiplayer.</h4>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var socketio = io();

    function changeColorClient () {
        socketio.emit("changeColorClient", {message: "changed color"})
    };

    socketio.on("changeColorServer", (message) => {
        text = document.getElementById("text");
        if (text.className == "uncolored") {
            text.className = "colored";
        } else {
            text.className = "uncolored";
        };
        console.log(message)
    });
</script>
</html>

